# Haskell Target Architecture

Tags: mysql, haskell

I am trying to use the HDBC MySQL driver in my project. I seem to be having a problem related to target architecture of the processor.

ld: warning: in /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

Since it can't read the file all the external references fail to resolve.

Do I need a different version of MySQL? Or can I retarget the target architecture of my build? Personally I think that I am in the later camp as I prefer to work in pure 64 bit environment.

Comment: That's just a warning, rather than an error.  Your problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Oops - did mean to hit enter.    
That's just a warning, rather than an error. Your problem may lie elsewhere. We need to know a lot more info: what OS, what haskell compiler/interpreter, how did it get there (build from src, cabel'ed, tar'ed), how did HDBC-MySQL get there, etc.

Comment: Looks like it's a problem of MySQL, not Haskell.

Comment: @Steve: is your os OS X? seems like you installed 64-bit GHC and have a 32-bit only installation of mysql..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that GHC was 32 bit and MySQL was 64 bit. 32 bit is the currently supported GHC architecture on OS X.

See [Hackage 2965](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2965) for more details on 64 bit GHC on OS X

I resolved this by uninstalling 64 bit MySQL and installing 32 bit MySQL.